# CTR plus a 64 bit integer when implement CTR encryption mode in C++

Tags: c++, casting, double, biginteger

I am trying to using library [BigInteger](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/) to convert a 128-bit binary  string (like 1101) to int (like 13). Because the 128-bit number may over the size of primitive types, I tried the BigInteger library. But I cannot use it with built-tin double type, because of type-cast error between double and BigInteger:

```
BigInteger binStringToInt(string s){
    BigInteger r = 0;
    for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        int hat = s.length() - i - 1;
        int num = s.at(i) - 48;

        r += num* pow(2, hat);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Cannot use this too:

```
r += num* (long)pow(2, hat);
```

That way can fix type cast error, but when hat is big, pow() will over the range of long.

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

There is no power function in BigInteger lib, you can go with:

```
BigInteger binStringToInt(string s){
    BigInteger r = 0;
    for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        int hat = s.length() - i - 1;
        int num = s.at(i) - 48;

        BigInteger digitValue = 2;
        for (int powIdx = 1; powIdx < hat; powIdx++)
            digitValue *= 2;

        r += num * digitValue;
    }
    return r;
}
```

There might be room for optimization if you know beforehand that you will be dealing with 128 bit numbers. (E.g. initializing digitValue to `pow(2, 128)` outside the loop and then dividing by two in each iteration).

**But**, what you could also do (might be a better implementation altogether) is to implement a bitshift operator for BigIntegers, that would allow you to build your number as you go, or even a bitwise or operator for setting bits directly.